# UDP packet drops when manipulating Windows explorer window

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sockets, network-programming

I am developing a application receiving up to 900 Mb/s of data, coming in via UDP (1036 bytes datagram size). Under "normal" circumstances (no system load and no user interaction), everything works fine: no dropped datagrams reported by the OS, nor by my application. When I start to click through the folder tree of the windows explorer, changing the contents of its main display pane, datagrams are dropped. I observe this by using the Windows Performance Monitor and by checking the sequence number baked in the payload of the datagram.
This goes to the point where for every click, several hundreds of datagrams are lost.

Receiver buffer sizes are increased (128 MB OS and even more for my application). I further observe that no buffer reaches its limit, if calls to

```
ioctlsocket(my_socket, FIONREAD, &readableBytes);
```

return an accurate amount of bytes. Highest observed values are under 2 MB.
I am not sure which other buffers may overflow and how to track their state.

The application is developed using Qt. Besides the UDP receiving thread, three other threads are in use. All of them are idle when there is no user interaction and the receiving thread is cut of. All of this is the case for every test setup reproducing the problem.

The first iteration of the receiving thread used a Qt UDP socket, and checked for the correct sequence number.

The second iteration used a plain WinSock calling recv(...), with checking of the sequence number done in another thread. This obviously increased the amount of threads. Both threads are communicating via a lock free queue, which is perfectly able to handle the read and write operations presented to it. Nevertheless, even if only the receiver thread is running (reading datagrams and discarding them), the same behavior as described above may be observed.

Even an implementation with multiple receiver threads (also only reading and discarding) shows the same behavior.

The problem may be observed even when the data rate drops to 330 Mb/s, but is then less frequent. It disappears at even lower data rates.

Yes I know that UDP does not guaranty delivery, but packets are obviously reaching my machine and are discarded with ample CPU time and buffer space available - which seems strange, to say the least.

What I want to know:

1. Is there any explanation for this behavior?
2. If so, what could be a possible solution?
3. If not, what could be checked to find the cause for this problem?

Any help or direction to follow would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simple explanation is that you're badly lagging behind the incoming stream. 2MB worth of buffered data is **huge** when you have 1kb packets! UDP is designed to give you current data, not stale data, and when you're 2000 packets behind real time, the network stack does what it should and starts to drop packets. That's entirely expected. You should maybe have a few dozen packets ahead of you, at worst case, not thousands.

You will have to rewrite your code to use modern overlapped I/O distributed across a number of high-priority threads, ideally using no-copy packet buffers that get filled directly by the networking stack.

Qt could do a better job at abstracting this out, but until someone implements it the best you can do is read about modern high-performance networking on Windows and do the work yourself.

Comment: UDP can be used for any data, not just _current data_. Ex, the torrent protocol uses it for transfer and, by definition, it has no _current data_.

Comment: I used "current" perhaps circularly to mean packets that are not far behind the most recently arrived one. The assumption is that packets arrive at a fixed rate. When so, the receive buffer filling is clearly due to the receiving code not being able to cope with the data rate. There's no point to retaining such packets, the queue will only grow, so they must be dropped. 2MB is ~22ms worth of data on a gigabit link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I assume you mean using WSARecv in overlapped I/O mode.